# DataFrame display not as expected

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I tried to color the title of the columns in purple, but what I got from the output doesn't seem aligned. Is there a way to fix it?

```
import pandas as pd

purple_text = '\033[35m'
reset = '\033[m'

list_1 = [12, 27, 33, 56, 11, 90]
list_2 = [43, 55, 76, 26, 84, 62]


df = pd.DataFrame({f'{purple_text} Numbers_1 {reset}': list_1,
                   f'{purple_text} Numbers_2 {reset}': list_2})

print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

[image: This is the output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue comes from the fact that this formatting is making header text an incorrect size.

In order to remedy this, you should use display settings, this one works fine:

```
pd.set_option('display.colheader_justify', 'left')
```

Results:
[Aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLzj2.png)